# Is it safe to reinstall headers?

Tags: kernel, compiling, gcc, make, linux-headers

Since I have [build problems](https://askubuntu.com/questions/906036/how-to-resolve-error-unexpected-bits-per-long) with specific headers I plan to reinstall the headers and try again. I could not find any information about reinstalling headers. Is it safe to just remove or purge and then reinstall similar to any other package?

That is, `sudo apt-get remove linux-headers-$(uname -r)` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't imagine an issue, but just to be safe I would try this first

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall linux-headers-$(uname -r)
```

From the `apt-get` [man page](https://linux.die.net/man/8/apt-get)

> --reinstall
>
> Re-Install packages that are already installed and at the newest
>   version.

Another useful option is `--dry-run` if you are ever unsure of what `apt` is going to do.

> --dry-run
>
> No action. Perform a simulation of events that would occur but do not
>   actually change the system.